# how do I stack unordered list into 2 separate rows

Tags: css, css-position

I'm completely stuck and  have been struggling with this for days because I'm not a developer and just learn from forums.

I cannot modify the li classes with the price and table, restriction on code blocks to generate this from my ecommerce platform. I would like to get the results displayed in two rows, qty on top and price on bottom.

96  150  300  450  600
8.06  7.66  7.26  6.86  5.97

```css
li.QtyTabQty {
  display: inline-block;
  /* text-align: right; */
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* float: right; */
  /* width: 100%; */
}
li.QtyTabPrc {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  /* width: 100%; */
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="none">

  <li class="QtyTabQty">96</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$8.06</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">150</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$7.66</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">300</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$7.26</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">450</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$6.86</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">600</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$5.97</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Can you change the HTML? That data could be better in a table instead a list.

Answer (score 2):

if you want use lists you can do with flexbox:

```css
.none {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  /* height is required */
  height: 50px;
}
.none li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  /* Modify padding as required */
  padding: 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="none">

  <li class="QtyTabQty">96</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$8.06</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">150</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$7.66</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">300</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$7.26</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">450</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$6.86</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">600</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$5.97</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome!.  But adding `width` to `li` will make the items overlap when list size increases. Better approach would be to remove the `width` and add `padding` if necessary.

Comment: You are right, I don't need the width, actually not doing anything

Comment: @Pugazh I used a width on the `ul` trying to keep the design of the OP, but I look okay changes you've made

Answer (score 1):

Another option...pretty close to what you already have.

```css
li.QtyTabQty {
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
}
li.QtyTabPrc {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="none">

  <li class="QtyTabQty">96</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$8.06</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">150</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$7.66</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">300</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$7.26</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">450</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$6.86</li>

  <li class="QtyTabQty">600</li>
  <li class="QtyTabPrc">$5.97</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: @blonfu, I think it works on IE too (tested in IE 11) but yeah, there is a top row problem on Firefox.

Comment: yes, in IE works also, sorry. @Pugazh posted a similar solution but not works in IE11 and Firefox and I thought yours neither

Comment: Would that be OK? (It's a hack, I know, but works on firefox too) http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/EyZKEM